# Origin of the Phrase Nichsof Nichsafti

Tags: sources-mekorot, words

In Yedid Nefesh, [some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yedid_Nefesh#Text) versions of the lyrics have the phrase "ki zeh kama nichsof nichsafti" ([some](http://www.bj.org/spiritual-life/music-of-bj/invitation-to-piyut-na/yedid-nefesh/) have nichsof nichsaf)

> because it is so very long that **I have yearned intensely**
>
> כִּי זֶה כַּמֶּה **נִכְסוֹף נִכְסַפְתִּי**

While the word נִכְסַפְתָּה appears once in tanach (Bereishit 31:30) as part of nichsof nichsafta, nichsafti does not appear at all [all text from here on out is lifted from Bar Ilan Responsa searches]. From what I can see, the first use is in the Abarbenel on Shemot 4:18

> וילך משה וישב אל יתר חותנו וגומר עד ויאמר ה' אל אהרן לך לקראת וגומר אחרי שגמר משה בלבו ללכת בשליחותו במאמר השם הלך מהר סיני אל מדין ודבר עם יתר חותנו ליטול ממנו רשות לשוב למצרים ואין ספק שלא אמר לו דבר מענין שליחותו ומה שדבר אתו האלהים אבל אמר לו בלבד אלכה נא ואשובה אל אחי אשר במצרים כלומר אלכה נא אל אחי אשר במצרים ואשובה מיד כי לא אתישב שמה ימים רבים אלא כדי לראו' בלבד העודם חיים כי **נכסוף נכספתי** לבית אבי ואחי ולכן ארדה נא שמה ואראה אותם ואשובה ארעה צאנך אשמור

After this, there are other commentators which quote the phrase like the Torah Temimah on Devarim

> יש מפרשים כסופים מלשון נכסוף נכספתי

The Alei Tamar on Sotah 5:1 seems to cite the phrase as if it were from the Torah itself

> התורה דברה כדרכה הלך הלכתי כי **נכסף נכספתי**, גנב גנבתי, והיינו מפני שכן דרך המקרא להוסיף המקור על הפעל לחיזוק הדבר

which seems to be a misquote of the Yerushalmi Yevamot 45a

> כרבי ישמעאל דו אמר לשונות כפולין הן התורה דיברה כדרכה. [בראשית לא ל] הלוך הלכת כי **נכסף נכספתה**  [שם מ טו] גנב גנבתי

The Imrei Emet connects this even more explicitly (on Re'eh) citing the Bereishit passage for nichsafti:

> הוא לשון נכסוף נכספתי (עי' בראשית לא ל)

and the S'ft Emet on Lech Lecha also refers to it as if it is a known and written source:

> כסף הוא בחי' חמדה ותאוה כמ"ש נכסף נכספתי

Is there another source for the Abarbenel's midrash-esque explanation of Moshe's thought process which would provide an origin for this phrase?

Comment: Offhand, I think the shoresh *kesef* may be related to *asaf* meaning "gathering". That may be part of why "money" is called *kesef* (and so is silver.) Maybe there's this sense of being "gathered in" with this phrase.

Comment: When we say נכסף נכספתי in Yedid Nefesh, we’re speaking in the first person. In Vayeitzei, when Lavan says נכסף נכספתה, he’s speaking in the second person. Are you specifically looking for someone who says this phrase in the first person? Because if not, Vayeitzei is as early as you’re going to get.

Comment: It seems like the Abarbenel is quoting some other medrash-like story and that the other meforshim aren't adapting but attempting to quote the phrase.

Comment: FTR, I agree with @DonielF, and I don't think you (or any other mefarshim) need to find any other source that actually has it in first person. -1

Comment: @רבותמחשבות so you aren't troubled by "כמ"ש נכסף נכספתי" and the citing it as having come from 31:30 (when the person was immaterial to the argument that was being made)?

Comment: @rosends nope...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות do you think the Alei Tamar made a mistake and/or that the Abarbenel had no source for the medrash he presents?

Comment: There is a difference between a mistake and not quoting exactly.  Did he also make a mistake on Haloch Halachta, which is in the same Passuk?  No, he wasn't being exact, because it didn't impact his point.

Comment: In terms of the Abarbanel, he may have a source for his midrash.  However, the entire language that he uses is culled from different stories in Chumash, as I will highlight in the following comment

Comment: Bereishis 47:1, Bereishis 18:21 Bereishis 30:31, in addition to the language of this passuk that he comments on, and Bereishis 31:30.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות the Abarbenel is on Shemot 4:18. Is he simply cobbling together a medrash based on snippets of words he found in Bereishit that bear a passing resemblance? So he adopts and adapts capriciously? And do I think the Alei Tamar made a similar mistake for halachti? Yes, certainly. His point was not about first person or second but he changed the persons to match the third example. Why would he not be exact when quoting a pasuk? Do we allow such sloppiness in general? Then others start confusing his mistake with what the text actually says. Sloppiness leads to more mistakes.

Comment: @rosends the idea is, that the poet who wrote yedid nefesh (the baal charedim) was just that, a poet. He paraphrases to construct his own new phrases. Abarbanel, like many others, uses the same tactic in his writing, although ultimately the idea is his, only he is using language that the reader is surely familiar with. as with the missquotes, it is fine, especially coming from the Torah Temima, but even with the rebbes of gur it is understandable. the mistake probably came from yedid nefesh itself.

Comment: @heshy I figured that the poet adapted - that's fine for poetry. I have a bigger question if he didn't adapt but quoted. If he adapted from the Abarbenel then is the Abarbenel writing a poetic and fanciful composition, or citing a source other than his own imagination? And is the A"T who wrote 400+ years later quoting the Abarbenel or inventing the parallel first person on his own? Then, are the Im"Em and Sf"Em accepting the Abarbenel or the A"T's creation, assuming it to be the exact language of the pasuk or that phantom source?

Comment: @heshy one other wrinkle -- if the variant dating of Yedid Nefesh to 1438 is accurate, then it predates the Abarbenel and his source is the poet, not vice versa which turns his commentary into pure poetics.

Comment: @rosends i googled it and found that you were acually right that abarbanel predates

Comment: @rosends remember that all these people were intimately familiar with the language, so a small tense variation does not need a source for the inspiration.